# Magento2.4.5: How to Products images on order detail page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want to show images item-wise in the order detail page in the backend like this image below.
[image]

**Any idea,?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **Viewmodel** for replace object manager.

**file**: Override **sales_order_view** file.

**app\code{{vendor}}{{modulename}}\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="custom_item_column" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Image</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
            <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">

                <arguments>
                    <argument name="view_model"
                              xsi:type="object">{{vendor}}\{{modulename}}\ViewModel\Custom
                    </argument>


                    <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="product_img" xsi:type="string" translate="true">product_img</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Ad_Sections::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**file** : *app\code{{vendor}}{{modulename}}\view\adminhtml\templates\order\view\items\renderer\default.phtml*

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer $block */
?>
<?php
/**@var Aureatelabs\ModuleName\ViewModel\Custom $viewModel */
$viewModel = $block->getData('view_model');
//$viewModel->getSomething();
$_item = $block->getItem();
?>
<?php
    $block->setPriceDataObject($_item) ?><tr>
    <?php $i = 0;
    $columns = $block->getColumns();
    $lastItemNumber = count($columns) ?>    <td>
    <?php $product =  $_item->getProduct();?>
    <?php
        $imagewidth=200;
        $imageheight=200;
        $image_url  = $viewModel->getProductImage($product ,$imagewidth, $imageheight );
    ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>" />
</td>
    <?php foreach ($columns as $columnName => $columnClass):?>
    <?php $i++; ?>        <td class="<?= /* @noEscape */ $columnClass ?><?= /* @noEscape */ ($i === $lastItemNumber ? ' last' : '') ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getColumnHtml($_item, $columnName) ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?></tr>
```

**File** : *app/code/{{vendor}}/{{module_name}}/ViewModel/Custom.php*

```
<?php

namespace {{vendor}}\{{modulename}}\ViewModel;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

class Custom implements ArgumentInterface
{
    protected $_productRepositoryFactory;
    protected $productImage;
    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $image
    ) {
        //$this->_productRepositoryFactory = $productRepositoryFactory;
        $this->productImage = $image;
    }
    public function getProductImage($product,$imagewidth,$imageheight)
    {
        return $url = $this->productImage->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')
            ->setImageFile($product->getSmallImage()) // image,small_image,thumbnail
            ->resize(380)
            ->getUrl();
    }
}
```

Ref : https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/adding-new-column-in-admin-sales-order-view-page/td-p/489785

Answer (score 1):

you need to edit below file

/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer/defult.phtml ( you need to copy into your theme or module)

replace file code with below code

```
    <?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
    <?php $block->setPriceDataObject($_item) ?>
    <tr>
        <?php $i = 0;
        $columns = $block->getColumns();
        $lastItemNumber = count($columns) ?>
        <td>
        <?php $product =  $_item->getProduct();?>
        <?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();?>
        
        <?php  $imagewidth=200;
        $imageheight=200;
        $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
        $image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'small_image')->setImageFile($product->getSmallImage())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl();
         ?>
         <img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>" />
        </td>
         <?php foreach ($columns as $columnName => $columnClass):?>
            <?php $i++; ?>
            <td class="<?= /* @noEscape */ $columnClass ?><?= /* @noEscape */ ($i === $lastItemNumber ? ' last' : '') ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getColumnHtml($_item, $columnName) ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: without using object manager

Comment: With Viewmodel you can replace object manager.